# bash/ shell script while statement

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new in shell programming ... basically I'm novice at all but I need a simple script to do while loop and execute a php script . I've tried the following :

```
!/bin/bash
i=0
 while[ i < 13 ]
  do
php /var/www/html/pos.php &
(( i++ ))
done
```

but for some reasons the syntax is not good ... I'm getting error  line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: You need spaces in the correct places.  The shell syntax frequently relies on spaces, and you need a space before and after the square bracket.  The first line should start `#!`.  Because you have no space (the shell will be looking for a command `while[`, which probably does not exist), the `do` is an unexpected keyword - there is no preceding loop that requires it, so you get the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively, you can use a `for` loop

```
for((i=1;i<=13;i++))
do
  php /var/www/html/pos.php &
done
```

since the for loop already creates the counter you, you don't have to declare a counter manually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a space between `while` and the left bracket `[`, and you need to  put the `do` on a separate line or use a semicolon (both of those are fairly common mistakes when writing loops). Additionally, the left bracket `[` is equivalent to [man test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html) which supports `-lt` but not `<`:

```
function doStuff() {
  local counter=0
  while [ $counter -lt 10 ]
  do
     echo $counter
     let counter=$counter+1
  done
}
doStuff
```

OR

```
function doStuff() {
  local counter=0
  while [ $counter -lt 10 ] ; do
     echo $counter
     let counter=$counter+1
  done
}
doStuff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
!/bin/bash
i=0
while (( i < 13 ))
do
    php /var/www/html/pos.php &
    (( i++ ))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

can't see your code, but it should be like this

```
while [ $i -ne 3 ]
do
   echo "on number $i of 3"
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Comment: no need to use `expr` since bash shell supports internal maths for addition

Comment: No need to use bashisms since expr provides more portability.

Comment: @william, the OP puts a tag on bash, so bashism it is.. OP also doesn't say he needs to write portable code.

Comment: @kurumi That merely indicates that he doesn't realize how useful portability is.  Why encourage him to limit the usefulness of the code for no reason?

Comment: @william. do you go around "criticising" code that is not portable? the double open braces `(( ))` is not portable as well, at least not on bourne shell, yet many solutions posted includes that. Are you going to comment on them one by one? 2nd, if everyone writes portable code, then their code must at least able to work on the old bourne shell. Why regress, instead of progress? If it was me, I won't recommend using shell language at all. Lastly, "usefulness of the code" ? `expr` is external, for efficiency, I would use internals instead. I find it useless to "argue" with you further on this.

Comment: @kurumi  This discussion began with you criticising the totallay appropriate use of expr.  The OP is possibly totally unaware of the fact that portability in shell languages is even an issue.  Portability is not about regression...it is about the real world issue of spending hundreds of hours updating non-portable code it to work in an environment in which the original authors were unaware of issues that arise when they follow some internet dude's advice to use a bashism when there was no need for it.

Comment: @william, no, i was stating an obvious fact, that OP is using bash and since he is using bash, he has the right to know how to use it productively. A lot of people who post question in SO regarding bash doesn't care about portability. Most just want to get the job done. One might find installing what is lacking to make it work beats having to spend hours figuring out "does this statement work in all other relevant shells? "  If that's the case, one should not even start working in a shell language. Picking up Perl/Python/Ruby would be better.

Comment: Lastly, about regression. I stand my point. In the course of writing portable code, one will often need to include external shell tools, like expr/awk/sed/ etc. making the end product totally inefficient. This means sacrificing portability for inefficiency. A computer and its software work hand in hand to increase productivity. If they is used to make things slower, then why use them at all. That's "regression" (my own definition).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you want to do something like:

```
i=0; while (($i<10)); do i=$((i+1)); echo $i; done
```